# Chrome Extension i18n: Split the messages.json file?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, internationalization

I’m internationalizing my chrome extension but I really have a lot of text to translate. For better handling of all the text it would like to have different messages.json files, e.g. one for all the text of the options page, one for the pop-up page, one for the background script, etc.

I have not found any information how to do that. Is it even possible?

Thanks and regards, Tensai

Comment: chrome.i18n can only use what's documented: a single file per language. You can use a bundler to facilitate developing like everybody does nowadays.

Comment: Unfortunate, but thanks anyway. Because I’m only a hobby programmer I am not familiar with all these “professional” development tools.